# Pycharm text highlighting format python3.6

Tags: python, pycharm

Anyone who know if it is possible to change the text highlighting?

When I write sql within """ the highlighting works perfect, however when I add the new 3.6 syntax with {} all highlighting except the one for the python string disappears.

Is it possible to decide (on a row level which language that should be highlighted?)

[image: text highlighting]

(I'm running Prof. Edition PyCharm 2017.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

It's a known [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23270), feel free to comment and vote.